# Appcelerator Titanium error message on closing iOS simulator

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

After I click 'Stop' button in Appcelerator Titanium IDE I get the following message:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
```

With no further explanation.

Anybody knows what is that? I just updated my titanium studio today(up to Titanium Studio, build: 1.0.8.201201262211), thank you.